# Mosquitto publishing issue?

Tags: mqtt, mosquitto

I had Mosquitto up and running on my Ubuntu 16.04 server.
I was using Owntracks on 2 cell phones and had them subscribe to the other's topic.

Then sometime last week both phones lost the other's topic, followed quickly by phone 2 not connecting to the MQTT as far as the log is concerned but the phone still reports as being connected.

Then today I added a new listener on port 8083 using webhooks. I was able to connect with a web admin interface and subscribe to phone 1's topic.

I subscribed using the CLI to see if I could publish from the web interface with phone 2's user to do some troubleshooting. When I disconnected and attempted to reconnect (with both phone 2 and phone 1 users) I was unable to reconnect to the MQTT.

I restarted the MQTT and I was able to re-establish the connection but now when I publish anything, nothing appears in the subscriber. Phone 1 doesn't show up any more, even the CLI will not publish properly.

I assume I've broken something in my config.

mosquitto.conf

```
pid_file /var/run/mosquitto.pid

persistence true
persistence_location /var/lib/mosquitto/
persistence_file mosquitto.db
log_dest file /var/log/mosquitto/mosquitto.log
log_type error
log_type warning
log_type notice
log_type information
connection_messages true
log_timestamp true
password_file /etc/mosquitto/pwfile
acl_file /etc/mosquitto/aclfile.acl

#Internal Listener
listener 1883
allow_anonymous false

#External Listener
#listener 8883
#allow_anonymous false
#certfile /etc/letsencrypt/live/home.fqdn.com/cert.pem
#cafile /etc/letsencrypt/live/home.fqdn.com/chain.pem
#keyfile /etc/letsencrypt/live/home.fqdn.com/privkey.pem

#Webhooks Listener
listener 8083
protocol websockets
certfile /etc/letsencrypt/live/home.fqdn.com/cert.pem
cafile /etc/letsencrypt/live/home.fqdn.com/chain.pem
keyfile /etc/letsencrypt/live/home.fqdn.com/privkey.pem
```

aclfile.acl

```
# This affects access control for clients with no username.
topic read $SYS/#

# This only affects clients with username "phone1".
topic owntracks/phone1/phone-1
topic read owntracks/phone2/phone-2

# This only affects clients with username "phone2".
topic owntracks/phone2/phone-2
topic read owntracks/phone1/phone-1

# This affects all clients.
pattern write $SYS/broker/connection/%c/state
```

Comment: Appears that something is wrong with my .acl file.
I commented it out in my config, reloaded the MQTT broker and I am able to publish from the web console, and from the CLI and receive it in the CLI subscriber

Comment: Your config file is missing the lines that identify the users

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before each `topic`/`pattern` block there should be a `user` entry to say which user they apply to:

```
# This affects access control for clients with no username.
topic read $SYS/#

# This only affects clients with username "phone1".
user phone1
topic owntracks/phone1/phone-1
topic read owntracks/phone2/phone-2

# This only affects clients with username "phone2".
user phone2
topic owntracks/phone2/phone-2
topic read owntracks/phone1/phone-1

# This affects all clients.
pattern write $SYS/broker/connection/%c/state
```

Comment: Now if I want all users to read and write to a topic (say for testing) could I do this?  
# This affects all clients.  pattern write $SYS/broker/connection/%c/state  
readwrite topic test

Comment: No, you can not apply lines that start with `topic` to all users, only lines with `pattern`. Read the man page https://mosquitto.org/man/mosquitto-conf-5.html